# Removing spaces and non-printable character in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

I am working with xml file using lxml etree xpath method. My code is

```
from lxml import etree
File="c:\file.xml"
doc=etree.parse(File)
alltext = doc.xpath('descendant-or-self::text()')
clump = "".join(alltext)
clump
```

I got the following output:

```
             "'\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\n\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tIntroduction\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tAccessibility\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\tOpening eBooks\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\
```

I want to remove spaces and all tabs from output, so I use another code but failed to get the desired output
Here is that code

```
import string
filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, clump)
```

I only want to get text from output which is "Introduction , Accessibilty , Opening eBooks"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind to do it using `regex`:

```
import re
clump = re.sub(r'[\n\t]+', ' ', clump)
```

If you want to put any other characters to remove, just place those inside the `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
''.join(clump.split())
```

Hope, that will solve the problem! To improve this, you can use re and I am using Sabuj's code:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[\n\t]+', ' ', clump.strip())
```